# Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance

Tags: c#, cmd, .net-core

I have executed the command `bcdedit /set current safeboot network` from whitin a C# application and this in the error I got in my terminal:

The element data type specified is not recognized, or does not apply to the
specified entry.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
Element not found.

---

This is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C  bcdedit /set current safeboot network & ping 8.8.8.8 -t";
//startInfo.Arguments = "/C ping 8.8.8.8 -t";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing the brackets around the word "current":

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C  bcdedit /set {current} safeboot network & ping 8.8.8.8 -t";
```